# Using IoC/DI Containers with run-time dependent constructor arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm converting my code to use an IoC Container with StructureMap. Trying to get my head around things, and I feel it's starting to 'click' and I can see how it makes so much sense with the back-end side.

However, I'm working my way down I've spotted a few sitautions where I'm not sure how to make it work. Specifically, the case where my original constructor did something important with an argument that isn't really a dependency, or something that will change at run-time.

Let's say I start with this (pre IoC Container), where I was passing my dependencies using a constructor, but also sending it an `ImportantObject` that's run-time dependent:

```
IMyPageViewModel myPageViewModel = new MyPageViewModel(importantObject, dialogManager, pageDisplay, viewModelProvider)
```

and here it is doing its constructing:

```
public MyPageViewModel(ImportantObject importantObject, IDialogManager dialogManager,IPageDisplay pageDisplay, IViewModelProvider viewModelProvider)
{
    this.dialogManager = dialogManager;
    this.pageDisplay = pageDisplay;
    this.viewModelProvider = viewModelProvider;

    importantObject.DoThatImportantThing();
}
```

Now, I'm migrating to use the IoC container, and at first I think I should do something like this:

```
//I need to create an instance to use, so I use my IoC container:
IMyPageViewModel myPageViewModel = container.GetInstance<IMyPageViewModel>();
```

then letting it resolve it's dependencies, however importantObject is something that's set at runtime. I can't register it as a dependency:

```
public MyPageViewModel(IDialogManager dialogManager,IPageDisplay pageDisplay, IViewModelProvider viewModelProvider, IContainer container)
{
    this.dialogManager = dialogManager;
    this.pageDisplay = pageDisplay;
    this.viewModelProvider = viewModelProvider;

    //however, here I have no access to the important object that I previously passed in my constructor
    importantObject.DoThatImportantThing(); //obviously error
}
```

I thought maybe I should be creating using 'new', and passing the IoC container:

```
IMyPageViewModel myPageViewModel = new MyPageViewModel(importantObject, container)
```

then letting it resolve it's dependencies in the constructor:

```
public MyPageViewModel(ImportantObject importantObject, IContainer container)
{
    this.dialogManager = container.GetInstance<IDialogManager>();
    this.pageDisplay = container.GetInstance<IPageDisplay>();
    this.viewModelProvider = container.GetInstance<IViewModelProvider>();

    importantObject.DoThatImportantThing();
}
```

But that strikes me as not a good idea, specifically, I can't run it with a test register and have it create a dummy/stub "MyPageViewModel" for unit testing.

The only other thing I can think of is to remove all the logic from the constructor and putting it in an initialize method, or property setters. However, this means I have to ensure that initialize is always called before use and it will hide errors/problems.

Are any of these options sensible, how should I manage passing a run-time dependent object in a constructor with Dependency Injection?

I tried to stray away from static factories, as I've read lots about them being anti-pattern/bad practice.

**Edit:** In response to Bruno Garcia's answer I decided to use a factory type pattern that holds the container and deals with object creation like this:

```
class PageProvider : IPageProvider
{
    public MyPageViewModel GetMyPage(ImportantObject importantObject)
    {
        //might just get, if it's a single only instance
        return MyPageViewModel(ImportantObject importantObject,
                               container.GetInstance<IDialogManager>(),
                               container.GetInstance<IPageDisplay>(),
                               container.GetInstance<IViewModelProvider>())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shed more light on the `ImportantObject` type and the `DoThatImportantThing` method? More specifically why are you doing this? Where does the line `IMyPageViewModel myPageViewModel = new MyPageViewModel(importantObject, container)` live now?

Comment: How is `ImportantObject` created?

Comment: In my experience, you lose the ability to use constructors when you apply DI.  I treat another method like the runtime constuctor (called `Initialize` or something), that generally takes things like an `Id` to fetch data from the repository.  You lose a few things, like readonly properties, but it's well worth it for the DI setup IMHO.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad I have a ViewModel that's associated with a particular model (representing a ship in this case). In the constructor this is used as an argument in the ViewModelProvider which ultimately calls a WCF service to populate the origional object with a bunch of data which it uses to operate.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm trying to use a general example, so it could be created a number of different ways I think, I'm hoping after i implement the IoC container it will be created using a GetInstance<IImportantObject>() somewhere so I can replace IImportantObject with a test stub.

Comment: Use a Factory pattern or some accessor that will give you object with out directly coupling the dependent class to it some like how DotNet Core has `interface IHttpContextAccessor { HttpContext HttoContext {get;} }`. That way you can pass all the dependencies in the constructor and and have access to the `ImportantObject` via its accessor to call you method

Comment: The error you are making is that your components depend on runtime data. This is a [bad practice](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: That's an interesting read. When you say "The error you are making is that your components depend on runtime data" you mean the problem is I'm Injecting that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StructureMap [supports passing arguments](http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/) to Resolve. This could help you with passing the `ImportantObject` to the Service you are resolving.

It's worth noting that if you pass your container around, things can get really messy really fast. Avoid using it as a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Ideally you'd use the container to resolve an entry point (e.g: Controller, Consumer worker) and from that point on, there's no direct use of the container anymore. If you need to control the lifetime of the dependencies you are taking into your constructor, there are a number of ways to go about that like:
Taking a `Factory` or a `Func<>`.

I suggest you reading carefully the docs of the Container you want to use to understand who controls the lifetime of objects (if a Component implements IDisposable, who's going to dispose it?). When are lifetime scopes created/disposed?

IoC Container's are great but it's very easy to find yourself troubleshooting memory leaks if you don't carefully understand the concept of lifetime ownership.

Comment: If I don't keep track of the container, how do I create new objects that have dependencies?

Comment: The Container won't become a complete substitute of the `new` keyword. Say you are using a Controller, which in turn creates ViewModels. The controller will be resolved by the container (e.g. it's dependencies injected via Constructor). The Controller will have what it takes to instantiate the ViewModel. If it requires a creational pattern, it will get injected a SomethingFactory of which it can call to get the object the ViewModel requires to be constructured.

Comment: And say the View-model has dependencies I just construct it explicitly using new, like in my first example in the question? Ultimately, my Container will just manage the singleton lifecycle objects like factories etc. It sounds like I shouldn't be using the IoC Container to construct the MyPageViewModel in my question.

Comment: That could've already been injected into the class who's going to create the ViewModel. Or some sort of factory (or Func<>) which you can use to get an instance. Note that internally, that Factory or Func could be using the Container to resolve the dependency. The goal is to avoid passing you container around. It will influence how you design things (for the best) Check that link about Service locator.

Comment: I see, I have actually read that article before when I was trying to get my head around how to do this properly, but must have slipped my mind while I was trying to absorb IoC. I think the container resolving factories is the way to go, I pretty much already kind of do this with my ModelProvider and ViewModelProvider, just need to extend it to the other things.